# Angular 14 creates a lazy chunk for a single service

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, chunks

I am working on an Angular 14 Application which has a lot of lazy-loaded feature chunks. I created a new service called utility.service.ts which has some basic helper functions. For some reason though Angular creates a completely new chunk for this service. There are many services in this application, all have the "providedIn: 'root'"-config. Still my new service is the only one who gets a completely new chunk and I don't understand why:

```
[INFO] Lazy Chunk Files                                             | Names           |  Raw Size
[INFO] default-src_app_common_services_utility_service_ts.js        | -               |  19.75 kB |
```

Why is that? There are several services used throughout the application, why does this one get a chunk? Any tipps where I could look for the cause?

Comment: Is imported by multiple lazy loaded modules  ?

Comment: Yes it is. But I thought this would create a chunk called common?

Comment: This allows to split the lazy loaded chunks to be as small as possible ! Why would load a whole "common" chunk for just 1 service ?

Comment: The behaviour isnt consistent though. If I import another service in multiple lazyloaded modules as well, it does not get its own chunk.

Comment: It depends it they are imported in exactly the same set of modules. I has to be the exact same set.

Comment: I tried recreating it by importing multiple service in multiple lazy-loaded feature-chunks (not the same sets, I dont have sets at all). 

Each main navigation link of the webpage is its own feature chunk. Say Link A and Link B. The UtilityService is imported in A and B => gets its own chunk. If I import another Service in A and B: NO new chunk!

Nothing changed, the utilityservice is still the only one with its own chunk, which doesnt make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems I found the reason: The utility.service was also imported in another service. This import is the reason for the new chunk...